# Customizing header and footer in all pages in magento

Tags: magento

I am a newbiew to magento I want to change my header and footer which will remain same for all pages
I want to achieve it through code without using admin panel

I have tried the following thing I have created a file local.xml which resides in my app\design\frontend\base\default\layout section and created a file header.phtml which resides in my app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\headers\header.phtml

```
<reference name="root">
 <block type="page/header" name="header">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/headers/headers.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I want to change my header in all the pages but I dono where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can try app\design\frontend\default\default\template\page\html\headers\header.phtml.

First try to add a your xyz or abc class with any html tags. Then clean magento cache. Open your site in private window.

May this will help you.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what you are trying to suggest

Comment: are you using any theme?

Comment: No it's just a installed version of magento I have not added any theme to it

Comment: You can try for example original code is :<h1 class="product-name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
and to check if we are in right file :<h1 class="product-name xyz"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
consider xyz. then check if your change is shown on element inspector. Don't forget to clean the magento cache and reload page with ctrl+shift+r.

Comment: app\design\frontend\default\default\template\page\html\headers\header.phtml or app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\headers\header.phtml

Comment: I mean that try to change the code to track the file first.